# Where's that page about privileges?

Tags: support

I've seen the page that lists privileges by level with links to explanations of how they work dozens of times, but for the life of me whenever I go to look for it I have to start googling.  There doesn't seem to be any direct link via the interface, and when I search in `help` I just get other questions.

Where's the page and is there a direct link that I've missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used to be able to get there by mousing over your name at the top of the page, but the new top bar eliminated that option. The only way to get there now is from the regular [help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) page, which is linked in the top bar:

[View a full list of privileges you can earn http://so.mrozekma.com/unix-help-privileges-link.png](http://so.mrozekma.com/unix-help-privileges-link.png)

Comment: As forseen this has changed. You now have to click Help in the menu bar, then Help Center and then Privileges.